# Timing individual slides in Keynote

Tags: keynote

I have a self-playing slideshow in Keynote, with 20 second transitions (each slide is shown for 20 seconds).

The last slide plays a movie, which is longer than 20 seconds. How can I set the transition to longer than 20 seconds for the last slide only?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider exporting the slideshow into a Quicktime movie and present that way instead of through Keynote. If the contents don't change much, or at all, this is easiest. You can use iMovie to splice the two movies together. Make sure to set the movie to loop.